# Any way to generate a Auto Login/Token Authentication Link?

Tags: authentication, token, access-token

I have an account that I do referrals on and instead of having to make an entire landing page, and provide users with my referral link - I'll just have them purchase from my account.

Is there any way I could generate a link that will automatically log users in without me having to reveal my password?

Answer (score 4):

You could definitely do this by using something like a JSON Web Token (JWT).

Basically, the way it works is like this:

- On your server, you create a JWT that is signed with a secret key (some random string that only your server knows).
- In your JWT, you include your user's account ID that you want the purchase to come from.
- You email this JWT to the person in a link, something like `https://mywebsite.com/order?token=<jwt-token-here>`.
- The user clicks that link.
- Your web server takes the token out of the URL parameters, and ensures it is valid (that the signature is good).
- Your web server then finds the account ID in the token, and retrieves that user account from your user database.
- You then LOG that user in using cookies or whatever, and direct them to the purchase page fully logged in!

This is a pretty typical web flow for what you're trying to do, and is a totally fine way to do things like this. There are tons of JWT libraries out there that make this easy to do, so it shouldn't be very technically challenging.

The only other thing you should know in regards to creating JWTs, is that you can set an 'expiration' time. You should DEFINITELY do this, as you don't want someone to be able to log in using your token months in the future. The best way to do it would to likely be generate a token that lasts for 24 hours or so, then email THAT to the user. This way, it expires after one day.

Last thing to know: there are actually quite a few auth libraries that simplify this stuff. I'm the author of one, myself: [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath). Depending on what you're trying to do, that might actually make your life wayyy easier as it can generate those tokens automatically, and handle session creations for ya.

Hope that helps!